# Plotting density graph to show likelihood

Tags: r, ggplot2, bayesian, probability-density

I want to plot a probability density distribution for likelihood calculation (in Bayesian statistics). Theta represents the true success rate.

If I attempt to plot probability for likelihood calculation:

```
  k <- 10   # number of successes
  n <- 100  # number of trials
  likelihood <- as.data.frame(dbinom(x=k, size=n, prob=seq(0.0001, 0.9999, length.out=10000), log = FALSE))
  ggplot(likelihood, aes(x=likelihood[,1])) + geom_density(fill="lightgreen") +
    labs(title = "Theta 1 Likelihood", x = "Proportion", y = "Density")
```

The graph produced is as follows:

[image]

This occurs because density values for probability values are extremely high and centered around 0 i.e. the chance of the likelihood value being 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003 etc is extremely low. `prob=seq(0.1, 0.9, length.out=10)` looks slightly better, but it is still not what I am after.

Is there a way to change the graph so that it can plot probability in a more graphically visible distribution? I am hoping to be able to do this without plotting a histogram. This is a graph that I would like to aim for:

[image]

Comment: have you tried `xlim()` and `ylim ()` in your `ggplot`, or are you looking for something different?

Comment: Something different. Im hoping to see values over an x-axis scale similar to my last graph (green). The values are so densely concentrated, that xlim and ylim would be practically ineffective anyways.

Comment: What about changing the x-axis to log10 scale? `scale_x_log10()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I received a warning message: Error in seq.default(min, max, by = by) : ‘from’ must be a finite number In addition: Warning messages: 1: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous x-axis 2: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density). I suspect it didn’t work well with my seq code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend irl informed me that I was essentially calculating the density of a density; I was obtaining a density plot from a density distribution (`dbinom`). So what I should have done was plotting x against y, instead of plotting a density distribution. This can be done with `geom_point`(there are so many points, it looks like a curve):

```
k <- 10   # number of successes
n <- 100  # number of trials
proportion <- seq(0.0001, 0.9999, length.out=10000)
density <- dbinom(x=k, size=n, prob=seq(0.0001, 0.9999, length.out=10000), log = FALSE)
likelihood <- as.data.frame(cbind(proportion, density))
ggplot(likelihood1, aes(x=likelihood1[,1], y=likelihood1[,2])) + geom_point(size = 0.1) +
  labs(title = "Theta 1 Likelihood", x = "Proportion", y = "Density")
```

[image]

Simpler alternatives to using 'ggplot' include:

```
plot(proportion, density)
qplot(proportion, density)
```